# Why are duplicate considered bad?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

**How are duplicate received?**

They are closed and/or downvoted even if they are good question with a completely different wording. Even if the original of the duplicate is an highly voted question.

Duplicates are a good example of what is describe [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?lq=1).

**Duplicates are helpful.**

Often, by googling to find an answer I stumble across the duplicate questions before the "original" one. If there was not a duplicate question that asked roughly the same thing but used different words, I might never have found the original one. Also, the same question asked differently sometimes help to understand it.

As the site is gamified, to push you to earn more reputation, I can understand why duplicate shouldn't earn reputation for the asker, but since the site try to generate the best questions and answers, having different wording for a question often greatly help.

My point is that asking good duplicate question should not penalize the asker but it should not benefit him either.

If anything, the original question should get some reputation bonus since it was so good that someone had the same question but asked it differently.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. The original question receives more attention every time a duplicate is closed, as people look at the canonical question. That way, indirectly, the original question asker is getting reputation. Asking duplicates is not bad, *per se*, but lack of research where the duplicate would have been obvious, or lack of general question quality *is*.

Comment: I don't see where you actually state, or point out how, in your question(?) that duplicates are considered bad.

Comment: There are questions with several thousand duplicates; most of them are very easily Googled. What exactly is the value they add?

Comment: If you clarify what you're trying to say, what your main points are, you can attempt to have your question re-opened.

Comment: why -14 in votes? To me this question is actually very clear. Is the downvoting the result of some other altercation?

Comment: @TobiasGassmann On meta, you vote to express your opinion. So a very good question can receive a lot of down vote if people don't share your opinion. Still, it's a bit strange to have opinion vote on the question instead of the answer...

Answer (score 19):

Duplicates, when identified as such, *can be* helpful. They act as signposts for searchers when they used different search terms than the original. (See: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).) Duplicate question askers aren't penalized, except insofar as they may get downvotes for "lack of research" if the question they were seeking is trivially easy to find with a cursory search.

Duplicates, when not identified, are bad because knowledge is spread out and harder to find. That's why we like to find and close duplicates: so the knowledge can be consolidated in one place.

Just because a question is closed as a duplicate doesn't mean that it can't be voted on, only that new answers can't be added. By all means vote up well-asked-but-duplicate questions.

Comment: *Some* duplicates are helpful.  Most aren't.  Most duplicate questions don't use radically different terminology, aren't written better than the canonical, aren't easier to find, don't have existing incoming links, etc.  *Most* duplicates just waste a bit of time for someone who needs to go find the canonical and then add no value.  Of course, those duplicates that do create signposts can add a lot of value, so it's not like they should be (or are) deleted on sight.  It's still important to keep the perspective though that duplicates are mostly sand with just a few pearls.

Comment: Granted, but is it always so easy to identify the pearls?

Comment: Further to what @Servy said, try searching for "[java] static context" on the main site. There are literally hundreds of questions with almost identical titles. Many people simply *don't bother searching* before posting, which takes away from the primary benefit of having the duplicates around.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Generally, yes, they are easy to identify.  Take question, copy paste sections into google/SO search.  If you can find the answer, the duplicate isn't adding value.  If you can't, and you need to throw in words not in the question to find your answer, the duplicate has at least a chance of adding value.  Most duplicates fail this test.  You can also look at the views that the question attracts over time.  If, from a few days after the question is closed to several months (or more) later we track the views that it refers to the canonical.  That represents its value.